# Understanding MySQL Locks and Deadlocks

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking, deadlock, mysql-8.0

I was just checking the articles regarding the MySQL table locking system. I wanted to learn about how we can avoid the deadlocks in MySQL while UPDATE/DELETE operations.

**What I have done so far:**

**Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx` (`a`)
);

START TRANSACTION;
truncate new_table;
insert into new_table(a) values(2),(3),(4),(5),(10),(11),(15),(19),(20),(25),(27),(35);
COMMIT;
```

- **Trial 1:**

**STEP 1:**

```
* SESSION 1:
    START TRANSACTION;
    delete from new_table where a in (2, 3, 4);
    insert into new_table (a) values (55);
    // Both the queries will be executed. (NOT COMMITTED YET)

* SESSION 2:
    START TRANSACTION;
    delete from new_table where a in (5, 10);insert into new_table (a) values(105);
    // waiting for lock

* SESSION 3:
    START TRANSACTION;
    insert into new_table (a) values(7); delete from new_table where a in (11, 15);
    // waiting for lock
```

**STEP 2:**

```
* SESSION 1:
    COMMIT;

* SESSION 2:
    ** DEADLOCK HERE **

* SESSION 3:
    // Both the queries will be executed. (NOT COMMITTED YET)
```

You see that there is deadlock in **SESSION 2**. What I think is, it is due to GAP locking in the MySQL (I might be wrong, correct me if I am wrong here).

To avoid Gap locking, I changed the GLOBAL Transaction isolation to READ COMMITTED (default is REPEATABLE READ). But still the same issue.

1. **Trial 2:**

**STEP 1:**

```
* SESSION 1:
    SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
    START TRANSACTION;
    delete from new_table where a in (2, 3, 4);
    insert into new_table (a) values (55);
    // Both the queries will be executed. (NOT COMMITTED YET)

* SESSION 2:
    SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
    START TRANSACTION;
    delete from new_table where a in (5, 10);insert into new_table (a) values(105);

* SESSION 3:
    SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
    START TRANSACTION;
    insert into new_table (a) values(7); delete from new_table where a in (11, 15);
```

**STEP 2:**

```
* SESSION 1:
    COMMIT;

* SESSION 2:
    // Both the queries will be executed. (NOT COMMITTED YET)

* SESSION 3:
    ** DEADLOCK HERE **
```

Notice the change, the deadlock shifted to the **SESSION 3**. As you can see, there are no overlapping rows which I am trying to delete. But still there is the deadlock anyhow.

When I try to execute above delete queries with `PRIMARY KEY` in `WHERE` clause, everything just works fine.

Can anyone explain me what is happening here? How can we handle such situations and avoid the deadlocks in MySQL?

**EDIT**: Adding the results of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

- Query: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * from new_table where a in (2, 3, 4);`

** With index column

```
-> Filter: (new_table.a in (2,3,4))  (cost=1.45 rows=4) (actual time=0.059..0.069 rows=3 loops=1)
    -> Covering index scan on new_table using idx  (cost=1.45 rows=12) (actual time=0.048..0.060 rows=12 loops=1)
```

** After removing index from the column

```
-> Filter: (new_table.a in (2,3,4))  (cost=1.45 rows=4) (actual time=0.034..0.043 rows=3 loops=1)
    -> Table scan on new_table  (cost=1.45 rows=12) (actual time=0.031..0.037 rows=12 loops=1)
```

** With PK

- Query: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * from new_table where id in (2, 3, 4);`

```
-> Filter: (new_table.id in (2,3,4))  (cost=1.36 rows=3) (actual time=0.040..0.050 rows=3 loops=1)
    -> Index range scan on new_table using PRIMARY over (id = 2) OR (id = 3) OR (id = 4)  (cost=1.36 rows=3) (actual time=0.038..0.047 rows=3 loops=1)
```

Comment: "*When I try to execute above delete queries with PRIMARY KEY in WHERE clause, everything just works fine.*" -  What does the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` show for each query (both when you use the primary key and when you don't)? This sounds like when you use column `a` you may be getting an index scan (or similar) operation that results in it needing to *touch* more rows than just the one's you're deleting, perhaps resulting in a larger lock. Whereas with the primary key you're likely getting a seek operation, which would potentially result in a smaller lock. The `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` should show this.

Comment: I have tried applying an index to column `a` and without it. Same results with both of them.

Comment: @J.D. BTW, I have added the response from `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` queries.

Comment: When you use `SET GLOBAL`, it does not affect current sessions. It affects subsequent sessions. Read the section "Transaction Characteristic Scope" in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-transaction.html.

Comment: @BillKarwin I have tried setting `GLOBAL` and `SESSION` both the isolation scopes multiple times. I can see no effect of them. And anyways, setting isolation scope to `GLOBAL` is not the solution of my problem, I was just playing around it.

Comment: `a` is a varchar (string) but you are comparing it with a number each time. I imagine if you treated it as a string or created it as a number data type you’d have a much nicer experience

Comment: @AndrewSayer No effect. I changed that column to `INT`, and executed same cases as described in the question but same behavior.

Comment: I understand you created an index on column `a` but I suspect it isn't being used efficiently even though it's there. One reason that may be so is like Andrew points out regarding column `a` being a string data type but you're comparing it to numbers. Comparing different fidelity data types can result in inefficient operations. Your `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` seems to agree because you're getting scans, *index scan*" for the first one. The primary key example is getting a range scan, which I'm guessing is more performant. Also, I was more curious about the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for the `DELETE` queries.

Comment: @J.D. `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for DELETE query is giving me this error `<not executable by iterator executor>`

Comment: Guys, I think yes @AndrewSayer was right. I converted that column to `INT` but without `INDEX` it was giving the same `DEADLOCK` error. But when I converted that column to `INDEX`, it suddenly started working fine. Thanks @J.D. and @AndrewSayer .

Comment: Your schema showed `INDEX(a)`; they were assuming that did not go away.

Comment: Yep, `INDEX` is there. But I was playing around without `INDEX` just to check the edge case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing a `VARCHAR` to a numeric literal is a pitfall that I sometimes see in `SELECT ... WHEREs`.  You seem to be experiencing the same thing in `UPDATE...WHEREs`.

The varchar is converted to numeric before testing.  This tends to cause full table (or index) scans.  In the case of `UPDATEs`, that tends to lead to locking all the rows in the table.

Quoting the literals would also solve the problem.

```
WHERE vc = 2   -- bad
WHERE int = 2   -- good
WHERE vc = "2"   -- good
WHERE int = "2"   -- good (the literal is interpreted as a number)
```

Fix the datatypes (as you noted) in order to fix the problem.  Or is there still a case?

**Functions and sargability**

- `WHERE column = function(constant)` *may* be able to use an index on `column`
- `WHERE function(column) = anything`*cannot* use an index on `column`.  See [*sargable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)
- `WHERE column + INTERVAL 7 DAY > NOW()` *cannot* use an index; the `+` is essentially a "function" in this context
- `WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(column) > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH` *cannot* use an index because of the [builtin] function `FROM_UNIXTIME`.  The right-hand side is a "constant expression" that is evaluated before executing the query; hence not a problem.

Comment: What about having a `Datetime` column and in the query comparing it against the `Long` (Timestamp) value? Example: `WHERE dateTimeToMilliSec(<date time col>) >= [some epoch timestamp]`. Will this still lock all the rows as in the case of comparing `INT` value against the `VARCHAR` column?

Comment: Is `dateTimeToMilliSec` a `BIGINT` in the table definition?  Then it is like `INT` in my list of 4 things.

Comment: `dateTimeToMilliSec` is a function which will convert `DATETIME` value to `BIGINT` value (i.e. Epoch TimeStamp)

Comment: So let's say I have a `DATETIME` column in the database table, but I want to compare it against the Epoch Timestamp, and I choose to convert `DATETIME` instead of converting Epoch Timestamp to `DATETIME`, then will it work?

Comment: And also, another question: if I execute same delete queries with `INDEX` columns in `WHERE` condition, from multiple sessions where transactions are still not committed, then it does not give any deadlock (though all the queries are exactly same). But if the column in `WHERE` clause are not `INDEX`, then it gives the deadlock. I am not able to understand why this happens.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri - I added more.